# Where to find data in database of sxc

Tags: 2sxc

I created an app with the sxc module.
Now I have like 500 empty rows which I want to delete.

I searched for them in the database to delete them all but I cannot seem to find them and I think it is a waste of time to delete them all 1 by 1.

It's data in "Manage content / data" table.

Let me know please.

I have another question: 
If I edit an item. The title of the module gets changed with the first items 'name' field. How to avoid that? Is it an bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, the data in 2sxc is not stored like typical relational data that you might be used to.  So I don't recomend trying to dig in the table for bulk updates.  I would suggest using their data import and export feature here:https://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Content-Export-and-Import

Comment: the module title is not a bug.  It is usually best to use a title-less module if you need full control of your design for 2sxc content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically JKings answer is correct - this kind of bulk-operation can easily be done using export/import, because on re-import you can tell 2sxc to delete all items not found in the import. This ensures that 2sxc can take care of data integrity etc. Instructions https://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Content-Export-and-Import

So the correct steps are:

1. export the list
2. open in notepad, xml editor (or use excel, as shown in the link)
3. Remove all those you don't want
4. Re-import, but choose the option to "Remove all entities not found in import"

You're set :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have one question left: If I export, remove all I don't want and import new file, are all these items getting different ID's then before? I have a template using those ID's.

Comment: Each item keeps the ID and the GUID, but just to be safe you should do a dry-run on another table with some test entries.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is working indeed. I just want you to know that the exported xml file has an incorrect ending. It ends with </SexyConten instead of </SexyContentData>

Comment: @DannyBrouwer are you using a current version of 2sxc? this used to be a bug but should be fixed